# Transform XML file using Tokenizer in VSO

Tags: xml, tokenize, azure-pipelines

In my cloud app service , I want to pass values to a XML file using release variables during deployment in VSO. The idea is to pass different values to the xml based on the environment its being deployed to.

I have couple questions about that,

1. Is the tokenize task in VSO only applicable for web.config transformation ?
2. If tokenizing a non web.config file is a possibility then ,how do I unpack CsPkg file to replace the transformed xml file?

In my release I am using Azure cloud service deployment step to publish csfg to azure.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are many tokenize tasks, such as [Replace Tokens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=qetza.replacetokens), [Tokenizer](https://github.com/openalm/Extension-UtilitiesPack/blob/master/Utilites/overview.md), you can use them to do it with other files.

Staring from Windows Azure SDK 1.5, the CsPkg file is the unencrypted package file, which you can unzip and visualize it contents. However it will throw FileFormatException during deploy if you change the file(s) and package (zip) the folders again.

So, I recommend that you can create the package after tokenize task (per to environment) during the release process. For this way, you need to publish source files to artifact during the build process.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I will try it out

Comment: @user2048598 What's the result after trying it?